# Determining if a Telescoping Series is convergent or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you determine if a telescoping series is convergent or not? If it converges, what value does it converge to?

It seems like you need to do partial fraction decomposition and then evaluate each term individually?

For example:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-n} $$

Comment: I'm not sure what you can say in general, other than "try to determine if it's telescoping."

Comment: Bad example: this one is absolutely convergent. No need to worry about telescoping anything. Indeed, if $x_n=\frac{1}{n^3-n}$, then $0\leq x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n^3+3n^2+2n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n^3}$. And the latter is the general term of a Riemann $p$ series which converges.

Answer (score 7):

A telescoping series is of the form $(a_1-a_2)+(a_2-a_3)+(a_3-a_4)+\ldots$. The terms in the sequence of partial sums are $a_1-a_2,a_1-a_3,a_1-a_4,\ldots$ and this converges if and only if $(a_n)$ converges.

Comment: In the example that he gives, the telescoping is slightly more complicated, though.

Comment: @SammyBlack How so? Consider $a_n=1/(2n(n-1))$.

Answer (score 4):

Partial fraction decomposition in your example yields
$$
\frac{1}{n^3 - n} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n + 1} \right]
$$

To see the telescoping of the sum, it's nice to arrange terms like this:

$$
\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3 - n} &=& \frac{1}{1} &-& \frac{2}{2} &+& \frac{1}{3} && && && \\
&& &+& \frac{1}{2} &-& \frac{2}{3} &+& \frac{1}{4} && && \\
&& && &+& \frac{1}{3} &-& \frac{2}{4} &+& \frac{1}{5} && \\
&& && && &+& \frac{1}{4} &-& \frac{2}{5} &+& \frac{1}{6} \\
&& && && && &+& \cdots &&
\end{array}
$$

Now it's clear that the $N$th partial sum $(N \ge 3)$ is
$$
s_N = \sum_{n = 2}^N \frac{1}{n^3 - n} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{N + 1} \right].
$$

The infinite series is the limit of these partial sums:

$$
\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3 - n} = \lim_{N \to \infty} s_N = \frac{1}{2} \biggl( \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} \biggr) = \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Comment: :What is, if any, the general form of the limit for the telescope: $(a_1-a_2)+(a_2-a_3)+(a_3-a_4)+\ldots$

Comment: You should ask a new questions, explaining more about what you're assuming, perhaps linking to this question and/or answer in the body of the post as well.

Comment: Short answer: the $N$th partial sum will be $a_1 - a_N$, so the series will converge if and only if $a_N \to L$ as $N \to \infty$, in which case the sum will be $a_1 - L$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the sum converges to $a_1 -Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n $

Comment: The pairwise differences will vanish $(a_n - a_{n+1} \to 0)$ (the summands in your series) as long as the terms $a_n$ converge to some limit $L$.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up , @Sammy Black.